# Extension of a function to a continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

The problem is the following:

Extend the following function to a continuous function defined on all $\mathbb R^2$

$f(x,y)=xy/(x^2+y^2) $

I have never solved such a problem. Would be thankful if anyone helped me with it

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This function is already defined on the whole plane, except for one point, so you just need to choose the value at this point. For continuity, you need the value of the function equal to the limit at this point (if this limit exists... does it?)

Comment: The problem is that you can't extend this function continuously to $\mathbb{R}^2$... Try to prove this using the idea in Mark's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $xy$ and $x^2 + y^2$ are continuous functions on all of $\mathbb{R}^2$, so $f(x,y)$ is continuous on all of $\mathbb{R}^2$ except where $x^2 + y^2 = 0$. So, where is $x^2 + y^2 = 0$? After you find this point, say $(x_0,y_0)$, then we just have to define
$$f(x_0,y_0) \equiv \lim_{(x,y) \to (x_0,y_0)} f(x,y)$$
to make the function continuous everywhere.

Comment: You're right, I should've actually checked to make sure the limit exists, which it does not.

Answer (score 0):

It can not be done since the limit of $f$ at $(0,0)$ does not exist.

$f(x,x) = \dfrac{1}{2}$, $\forall x \neq 0$, and $f(x,x^2) = \dfrac{x}{1+x^2}$

I hope this helps.